# Making a website subfolder with complex content accessible only to members

Tags: php, authentication, middleware, wiki

I am developing a simple website for a community organization where we want to have, among other content, a wiki that is only visible to registered users who are logged-in.

Using some of the many excellent resources online, I put together a php-and-database based authentication system that handles user registration and session-based authentication. I can successfully call a php function that gives me a visitor's logged-in status.

But now, I am a little stuck on how I actually use this logged-in status to protect entire parts of my website, i.e., complex content in subfolders such as my wiki installation that is in `/wiki`. I have tried implementing an example where I can protect individual files by using `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` and then a method that uses `header()` and `fpassthru()`, such as the example [here](https://www.eriksmistad.no/how-to-restrict-user-access-to-content-in-folders-using-php-and-apache-htaccess-files/).

But this method doesn't seem to work when I want to protect an entire folder that itself contains php, such as the contents of my `/wiki` folder (a mediawiki installation).

(Note I don't particularly want to just use mediawiki's access control, because I want to have other content behind the login page beside the wiki.)

Further research brought me to the concept of "middleware" to control access to whole subdirectories, but have to admit I am a little out of my depth and haven't found a simple example yet of how I might implement this (maybe I am not searching for the right keywords).

I would be grateful if anyone could point me towards a resource and/or example for protecting subfolders on a website.

Comment: What do you mean by _“protect an entire folder that itself contains php”_? Protect _what_, exactly? The directory listing from being shown when the folder gets requested? Or the individual PHP files within? Well if you already have a session-based system in place - then implement it inside those as well …? (If you don’t want to have to manipulate too many individual files, then the `auto_prepend_file` setting might be able to help with that.)

Comment: Update: I am looking at using apache `mod_authnz_*` to solve this but still not exactly sure which mod to use or how I implement it.